# How do I pass ttf (font) file from a dll Resource folder to a Font field without using PrivateFontCollection?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, fonts, resources

Before i go into detail. If there is a problem with the question. leave a comment stating what the problem is.

I am already able to access the path to the Font file in my dll Resources folder. I just need to pass the data to a Font field . Here is how I access the path and Font data in my dll.

If there is a problem with the question. leave a comment stating what the problem is.

Just to mention , this class exists inside my dll.

```
class ClassA
{
public Font myFont;
void GetFontDromDLL()
{
          Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                     Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(myAssembly.GetName().Name + ".Resources.Awesomefont.ttf");
         //myFontfont = ?

}


}
```

from that point on how do i assign it to `myFont`

If it is that i first need to create a byte array from `myStream` then i can do that . I still can't pass it to the Font field `myFont` , I don't know how

For my project I am unable to use System.Drawing  and anything extending from System.Drawing as I am working in the Unity Engine, 
so using `System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection` is out of the question.

thanks for any help

Comment: If you cant use System.Drawing, then what namespace does the type `Font` come from used in your example code?

Comment: Thanks for asking .  I am using Unity.Engine.Font

Comment: You may want to [edit] that information into your question.  (You also probably want to add the `Unity` tag.)

Comment: Thanks . I edited the question.